# Does the comma go inside or outside the end quote when the subject speaks and then does an action

Tags: commas, quotation-marks

I have the following sentence and am struggling to work out where the comma goes. Should it be:

She said, 'I understand', and walked away.

or

She said, 'I understand,' and walked away.

Many thanks.
Jo

Comment: In the standard rules for American English, the comma *always* goes inside the end quotes. In the standard rules for British English, the comma goes inside the quotes only if the quotation itself should end with a comma or period. (Although not all publishers in these countries follow the standard rules.) So in this instance, both rules agree.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. I'm using British English so, according to this rule - as the quotation should end in a full stop - I will place the comma inside the closing quote mark.

Answer (score -1):

The comma goes inside the quotation marks, when it's followed by further information.

Comment: A good answer would explain why.

Comment: I don't know why - it just does.

Comment: Thank you for this.